# MySQL: join where not equal to

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, left-join, where-clause

I want to write a query that displays photos that user 5 did **not** like. Photos and likes are 2 tables joined by Photo_Id / Image_Id.

To display photos that user 5 **did** like I write:

```
Select
 wp_photos.Photo_Id
From
 wp_photos inner Join
 wp_photos_likes On wp_photos.Photo_Id = wp_photos_likes.Image_Id
Where
 wp_photos_likes.From_Id = 5
Group By
 wp_photos.Photo_Id
```

I would like a query that displays all photos that user 5 (From_Id) did **not** like. 
Trying

```
 Where
  wp_photos_likes.From_Id <> 5
```

Does not work as other users liked photos that user 5 liked and so returns these as well. 
I tried some left joins but with no success. 
What's the correct query?

Comment: You're supposed to know [this](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ydUTsFd11Ok/UiV8EKJezWI/AAAAAAAACUQ/-pWSuWnv4yU/s1600/sql+joins.jpg) instead of trying each join to see how it will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `left join` antipattern:

```
select p.photo_id
from wp_photos p
left join wp_photos_likes l
    on p.photo_id = l.image_id and l.from_id = 5
where l.image_id is null
```

This phrases as: check if each `photo` was liked by user 5, and filter on thoses who were not.

Another way to solve this is to use a `not exists` condition with a correlated subquery:

```
select p.photo_id
from wp_photos p
where not exists (
    select 1
    from wp_photos_likes l
    where p.photo_id = l.image_id and l.from_id = 5
)
```

Comment: @emix: people tend to find `right join`s harder to understand and maintain, and usually prefer `left join`s (I personnaly do).